# Why can not reference a type through an expression?

Tags: c#, types, casting, enums

The following code seems to be impossible to compile no matter how hard I am trying to cast it :P can somone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
public class LUOverVoltage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public enum OVType { OVLH, OVLL }

    public List<string> PinGroups = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string name, OVType type, string Grp)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.OVType = type; //Why cannot reference a type through an expression?

        PinGroups.Add(Grp);
    }
}
```

Comment: What compilation errors do you get?

Comment: 'OVType': cannot reference a type through an expression;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're confusing a field that has an enum type with the enum type itself. Your code is about as useful as saying `string="bla"`.

```
public enum OVType { OVLH, OVLL }
public class LUOverVoltage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OVType OVType { get; set; }
```

This declares a type called `OVType` and a property with the same name. Now your code should work.

---

As a side note, both your type names, and the property names violate .net naming guidelines.

I'd name the enum type `OverVoltKind` and the property just `Kind`.

Answer (score 4):

You're not setting a property, you're trying to set the enum.

Add a `public OVType ovType` and use `this.ovType = type`.

```
public class LUOverVoltage
{
    public enum OVType { OVLH, OVLL }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OVType ovType;
    public List<string> PinGroups = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string name, OVType type, string Grp)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ovType = type;

        PinGroups.Add(Grp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined an `Enum` inside your class. What you have not done is declare a variable to hold an instance of that enum.

```
public enum OVType { OVLH, OVLL }

public class LUOverVoltage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OVType OVType { get; set; }

    public List<string> PinGroups = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string name, OVType type, string Grp)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.OVType = type; // setting the property, not the enum definition

        PinGroups.Add(Grp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OVType - is not a field, its a type

Try this

```
public class LUOverVoltage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OVType Type {get; set;}

    public enum OVType { OVLH, OVLL }

    public List<string> PinGroups = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string name, OVType type, string Grp)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Type = type;

        PinGroups.Add(Grp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OVType` is the type of the variable. You have set it to [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which is the keyword used to declare a new enum type. You need to declare OVType as an enum type, then use that as the property type.

```
public enum OVType { OVLH, OVLL }

public class LUOverVoltage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OVType OVType { get; set; } 

    public List<string> PinGroups = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string name, OVType type, string Grp)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.OVType = type;

        PinGroups.Add(Grp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not make it any better.

Comment: public OVType OVType { OVLH, OVLL } wont compile

Comment: Ah! As if I missed that. Updated now.