# Converting a string to a custom enum

Tags: c#, enums, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

I'm trying to set a custom enum property on a custom object by looking at a string value that is held in another object, but I keep getting the error "cannot reference a type through an expression."

so far I've tried

```
rec.Course  = (CourseEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(CourseEnum), rr.course);
```

where rec.Course wants a member of the CourseEnum Enumeration, and rr.course is a string.

I also tried to do a switch statement where the value of `rr.course` is checked (there are only certain values it can be) but get the same result

the enum is defined as follows:

```
public enum CourseEnum
    {
        [StringValue("Starters")]
        Starters,
        [StringValue("Main Course")]
        MainCourse,
        [StringValue("Desserts")]
        Desserts
    };

public class StringValue : System.Attribute
{
    private string _value;

    public StringValue(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

}

public static class StringEnum
{
    public static string GetStringValue(Enum value)
    {
        string output = null;
        Type type = value.GetType();

        //Check first in our cached results...

        //Look for our 'StringValueAttribute' 

        //in the field's custom attributes

        FieldInfo fi = type.GetRuntimeField(value.ToString());
        StringValue[] attrs =
           fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValue),
                                   false) as StringValue[];
        if (attrs.Length > 0)
        {
            output = attrs[0].Value;
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't confuse the terms `enum`/ *enumeration type* and *enumerator* (related to the `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` interface), which refer to two very different things in C#.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? What is definition of the code `rec.Course` and `rr.course`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper honestly I wasn't sure, but thank you for informing me

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048159/why-can-not-reference-a-type-through-an-expression

Comment: You show code for where `recipeCourse` is defined, but not where `CourseEnum` is defined. Could you show that code and what the value of `rr.course` is and where `rec.Course` is defined. Most likely Course is actually defined as an enum definition not a field containing an enum.

Comment: @Cornelius where i had put recipeCourse is actually CourseEnum, my mistake, however, I think you may have just given me my answer. I had defined the whole enum in the class, instead of just a field. I changed this and it now works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A @Hans Kesting said, the answer was here: [Why can not reference a type through an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048159/why-can-not-reference-a-type-through-an-expression)

The problem was using a field that has an enum type with the enum type itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your code that your using `Enum.Parse` with CourseEnum and it should be `recipeCourse` I presume.

I can't spot any place in your sample code where4 `CourseEnum` is defined.

Comment: If you run the OP's code, you can see that it actually gets `"Main Course"` for `recipeCourse.MainCourse`

Comment: @L.B.: could you explain a bit more what's wrong with the snippet I've provided? Question is about converting string to a custom Enum, and this is what the snippet does. Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: Yes there is. The question is not *"How can i do that?"*, question is about *"cannot reference a type through an expression."* error, and the answer is most probably here [Why can not reference a type through an expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048159/why-can-not-reference-a-type-through-an-expression) as pointed in previous comments

Comment: @L.B. I had a look at the other SO question, and my answer would be to move OVType's definition outside the class (and it was suggest by some people already). I can't see the same thing in here.